# If $\rho_{12}$ =0, show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are jointly normally distributed random variables with joint probability density function

$f_{x_1x_2}(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2(1-\rho_{12}^2)}}e^{-q/2}$

Where $q = \frac{1}{1-\rho_{12}^2}\left[\frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2} - 2\rho_{12}\frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)(x_2 - \mu_2)}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2}}+\frac{(x_2 - \mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\right]$

If $\rho_{12} =0$, show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

I have substituted $0$ for $\rho_{12}$:

$f_{x_1x_2}(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2}}e^{-q/2}$

Where $q = \left[\frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2} +\frac{(x_2 - \mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\right]$

Now I must show that $f_{x_1x_2}(x_1, x_2) = f_{x_1}(x_1)f_{x_2}(x_2)$ to show independence.

Since both variables are continuous:

$f_{x_1}(x_1) = \int f(x_1,x_2) dx_2$

$f_{x_2}(x_2) = \int f(x_1,x_2) dx_1$

But to be honest, I am stuck at this point. Things are getting too ugly and messy. Any tips? Am I not seeing a simple solution?

Comment: This follows immediately since $e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$.

Comment: The joint distribution of your variables is Bivariate Normal. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)

Comment: @StefanHansen But I have to take the integral of $f(x_1,x_2)$, right? I am not sure how the property of exponents helps here?

Comment: No need to integrate anything. If the joint density $f$ of $(X_1,X_2)$ factors into a product of two non-negative functions $g$ and $h$, i.e. $f(x_1,x_2)=g(x_1)h(x_2)$, and both $g$ and $h$ integrates to 1, then you may conclude that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent _and_ that $g$ and $h$ are the densities of $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively.